# How to make custom PhotoEffects in Django Photologue?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, photologue

I'm creating an image gallery in Django using the [Photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) application.  There are a number of [PhotoEffects](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/wiki/PhotoEffect) that come with it.  I'd like to extend these and make my own so that I can do more complicated effects such as adding drop shadows, glossy overlays, etc.

Is is possible to create custom effects that Photologue can then use to process images that are uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of Photologue. I would suggest you look at the 3.x branch of Photologue and more specifically, django-imagekit, the new Library it's based on: http://bitbucket.org/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/wiki/Home. One of the goals of ImageKit was to make it easier to extend Photologue. All effects and manipulations are now implemented as "Processors" which are just a class wrapping a function that takes a PIL image, does something, and returns it. These processors are then chained together in whatever configuration you like. The 3.x branch is early and has been neglected lately (I'll spare you the excuses) but it shouldn't be hard to drop in the latest release of ImageKit and have close to feature parity with Photologue 2.x.

Comment: I was contemplating sending you this link directly but didn't want to bother you.  Glad to see you found it!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could define another preset effect in the utils file, and then import it into models.py. Then you'd want to add it as an option to the PhotoEffect class in models.py. This would of course make your Photologue a bit custom to your needs though.